# Convert decimal value to ascii

Tags: python

I'm working on a tool that converts different format like HEX, BIN etc to different ones.

The whole thing has worked well so far...till now.

I know about the chr() function to convert a single character Decimal value to an ascii character
but I'm wondering how this can be done with a whole string, and how, if I were to loop through every character, the programm would know if it  should split the string on 1,2 or 3 positions.

What I'm aiming to accomplish:

```
116101115116 >> test
```

Comment: How would such a program know where to split the number for a new character? Is `116101115116` split as `116, 101, 115, 116`, or `11, 610, 1115, 116`, or any of the many many other possible combinations?

Comment: Instead of complicating this, you can simply tell the user to enter the numbers in the format  'a b c d' (In this case:116 101 115 116) and then use split() to work with the individual values.

Comment: @bot-coder101 Yeah right. If I don't find any other solution I'll use that technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this "number" is actually being stored as a `str` string, and you have explicit guarantees that the "chunks" of ASCII codes are let's say every 3 characters then this is pretty easy, you could do something like this:

```py
def convert_code_to_text(code):
  """Convert a string of numbers to a work"""
  # Assuming each chunk of character codes is always 3 digits long
  chunk_size = 3
  
  code_length = len(code)
  chunks = code_length // chunk_size
  my_word = []
  
  for chunk in range(chunks):
    my_word.append(chr(int(code[chunk*chunk_size:(chunk+1)*chunk_size])))
  
  return ''.join(my_word)

my_code = "116101115116"
word = convert_code_to_text(my_code)
print(word)
```

and this will return `test`. Now if you are *not* dealing with a `str` string of numbers but in fact an `int` or a `float` then you are in trouble. That will not work because sometimes ASCII character codes are only 2 digits long not 3, which means if the code for the word starts with one of those letters then the first digit will be zero and when that is converted to a numeric type the number will be dropped and you will not have a code that is cleanly divisible by 3.

Comment: I know that they can be 1 2 or 3 characters long but since I'm reading in a string and I have no guarantee that it will be only 3 character long chunks this doesn't work for me. Thanks for the help bud!

Comment: Without some kind of a delimiter I do not think it can be done.

Comment: I think @bot-coder101's answer above will be the next best thing.